# I get this error from my web service: error 1053 the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Tags: c#, windows, service, printing, silent

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Print();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                File.AppendAllText(@"C:\fold1\Log.txt", ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Print()
    {
        //Print & Move the files after printing
        DirectoryInfo sourceinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\A");
        DirectoryInfo target = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\A1");

        foreach (FileInfo fi in sourceinfo.GetFiles())
        {
            if (fi.Length != 0)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process.StartInfo.Verb = "print";
                process.StartInfo.FileName = fi.FullName;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                process.Start();

                if (!process.WaitForExit(1000))
                    process.Kill();
            }

            MoveFile(fi.FullName);
        }
    }

    public static void MoveFile(string Filename)
    {
        string SourcePath = @"C:\fold";
        string targetpath = @"C:\fold1";

        if (!Directory.Exists(targetpath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(targetpath);
        }

        string[] sourceFiles = Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath);

        foreach (string sourcefile in sourceFiles)
        {
            string mfilename = Path.GetFullPath(sourcefile);
            string mname = Path.GetFileName(sourcefile);

            if (mfilename == Filename)
            {
                string distnition = Path.Combine(targetpath, mname);
                File.Move(mfilename, distnition);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        File.AppendAllText(@"C:\fold1\stop.txt", "Stop method");
    }
}
```

I'm trying to silently print files via a Windows service, I use this command to install it:

```
SC CREATE "MyServiceName" binpath = "My service's path"
```

but I can't even start my service, I get the error 1053. It takes too long to start and when it does, it only does one part of my code.

Let me explain: my code is supposed to print the pdf files in a directory and then move them to another directory, but when I get this error, it only does the moving part, it doesn't print the files.

Comment: Put any long running work in a separate thread, the `OnStart` method has to return quickly.

Comment: Already did , same problem

Comment: Post the updated code, if that is the case.

Comment: I posted it , I reduced the timer from 10 seconds to 1 , It's the same problem

Comment: You have an endless loop in `OnStart`. You can try using a [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-5.0), but I doubt you'll succeed printing pdf files (with adobe reader?) from a service.

Comment: So you're saying it's impossible to print from a web service? and

Comment: I removed the endless loop in onstart and I don't get the error anymore but the service doesn't do what  I wanted , I want it to silently print all the pdf files in the a directory and then move them , It doesn't do the printing at all it just do the moving part

Answer (score 0):

The OS requires `OnStart` to return quickly (within a few seconds), but your `OnStart` contains an infinite `while (true)` loop!

The simplest solution would be to wrap the contents of `OnStart` in a lambda expression and use `Task` to run it on a separate thread, allowing `OnStart` to return immediately. This code also uses [cooperative cancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads) to exit the task gracefully when `OnStop` is called.

```
private CancellationTokenSource cts;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args) {
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource(); // CTSs are only good for one cancel
    Task.Run(() => { // This lambda expression runs on a different thread
        while (true) {
            if (cts.IsCancellationRequested) return; // Check if we should stop
            ...
        }
    });
}

protected override void OnStop() {
    cts.Cancel(); // Tell the other thread it should stop
    cts.Dispose();
    ...
}
```

Comment: I removed the endless loop in my code and it started , I don't get the error anymore but there's another problem : the service doesn't print the files , it just move them !!!

Comment: I read the documentation you sent me but I got a bit confused as I'm a still a beginner in C# , can someone please help get through this project?

Comment: @RamadanAbdinour Currently your code waits one second before killing the print process. Are you sure that's long enough? You should also let it create and show a window while you're figuring this out - there might be helpful error messages on the console.

Comment: I upgraded the waiting time to 18 seconds , but I still get the same problem , it skips the printing part and just keeps on moving the files

Comment: Well then clearly something's wrong with your `Print` method. Are you sure that the `print` verb doesn't pop up a confirmation dialog? (Which you may not be seeing because of how you've set `CreateNoWindow` and `WindowStyle`?)